# Cannot download URLs in Java 6 or 7 - works in Java 5

Tags: java, httpconnection

We've got some pretty basic code to download the contents from a URL.  It works fine for the most part, however we've come across a couple or urls where it doesn't work in j6 or 7, but does in j5.

It's fairly standard code:

```
URL url = new URL(sUrl);
URLConnection urlCon = url.openConnection();
if (debug)
    System.out.println("GETURL DEBUG : set user aganet");
urlCon.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "SportsPunter.com Robot");
urlCon.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
urlCon.setUseCaches(false);
if (debug)
    System.out.println("GETURL DEBUG : set more properites");
InputStream is = urlCon.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = null;
String urlencoding = urlCon.getContentEncoding();

if (debug)
    System.out.println("GETURL DEBUG : got url encoding " + urlencoding);

if (urlencoding == null)
    urlencoding = "";
if (urlencoding.toLowerCase().indexOf("gzip") != -1) {
    if (encoding.length() == 0)
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(is)));
    else
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(is), encoding));
} else {
    if (encoding.length() == 0)
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    else
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, encoding));
}

String buffer = "";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(suggestedSize);

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (debug)
    System.out.println("GETURL DEBUG : start reading");

while ((buffer = br.readLine()) != null) {

    if (debug)
        System.out.println("GETURL DEBUG : got buffer " + buffer);
    // irrelevant code snip
}
if (debug)
    System.out.println("GETURL DEBUG : finished");
```

One URL that doesn't work is:
http://www.beteasy.com.au

The output when run in java 6 (/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64) or java 7 (jdk1.7.0_71) is as follows:

> GETURL DEBUG : start at Tue Oct 28 21:13:52 EDT 2014
>   GETURL DEBUG : check time to live
>   GETURL DEBUG : set user aganet
>   GETURL DEBUG : set more properites
>   GETURL DEBUG : open input stream
>   GETURL DEBUG : got url encoding null
>   GETURL DEBUG : start reading
>   GETURL DEBUG : finished

As you can see the very first call to readLine() returns an EOF.  It's the same if we use read() instead of readLine()

However, if we change to use Java 5 (jre-1.5.0)

Then the buffer gets read no problem at all.

One point of interest is that both of these URLs appear to redirect to a https connection.

We've been having some connection problems with some feeds that made changes due to heartbleed.  Our solution for these was to set the system property:
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");

instead of what we used to have:
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3,SSLv2Hello");

However, either value of this property results in the same thing.

If we try to download the https version directly, we get this:
[danielk@robot classes]$ ./geturl "https://www.beteasy.com.au"
GETURL DEBUG : start at Tue Oct 28 21:44:28 EDT 2014
GETURL DEBUG : check time to live
GETURL DEBUG : set user aganet
GETURL DEBUG : set more properites
GETURL DEBUG : open input stream

Again, in Java 5, we do not get this exception, and data is successfully downloaded from the URL.

Here is the code we have setup to supposedly accept any certificate:

Comment: did you try `url.openStream()` ?

Comment: Your code at the end is missing...

Answer (score 0):

I have used curl to test the url, the http url will respond a 302 status code, redirect to https url.
I don't think URLConnecton will deal with the 302 status automatically, cause it is from http to https, it will automatically redirect from http to http only. I think it is security concern.
So you can handle it manually, check the status code, if it is 302, and the Location head is a https, then you can open a new connection to the https url.